# How to test fragment UI with Espresso?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso

I have such fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F1F1F1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.92" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.07" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/logo_guideline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

            
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_holder"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:labelFor="@id/first_input"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:textColorHint="#333333"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo_guideline">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:labelFor="@id/login_input"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textColorHint="#333333" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/password_holder"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
                android:labelFor="@id/password_holder"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:textColorHint="#333333"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_holder"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="#333333">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:labelFor="@id/password_input"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textColorHint="#333333" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password_holder" />

            <com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/request_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:translationZ="2dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/login_button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/login_button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/login_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/login_button"
                app:mlpb_arrow_height="2dp"
                app:mlpb_arrow_width="7dp"
                app:mlpb_enable_circle_background="false"
                app:mlpb_progress_stoke_width="2.5dp"
                app:mlpb_show_arrow="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot_pass_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_button" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</layout>
```

and here is test which I'm trying to add:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginUITest {

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<LoginScreen>(
            initialState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun testFragmentElements() {
        onView(withId(R.id.login_holder)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }


    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        //clean up code
    }
}
```

there are problems:

- my `R.` is not visible, red highlighted. Only if I add it manually to import
- when I'm trying to launch this test on my emulator does not show any app, only I see in AS status `Gradle build`
- how to check requests in ui tests, like to the api? or it is only about UI?

Maybe I have to add some more dependencies to `build.gradle`, at this moment I have:

```
dependecies{
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.5.1'

}
```

### UPDATE

Also when I interrupt build after 10 minutes I can see such error in the logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.PlatformTestStorageRegistry" on path: DexPathList
```